# What are invariants, how can they be used, and have you ever used it in your program?

Tags: invariants

I'm reading *Coders at Work*, and in it there's a lot of talk about invariants. As far as I've understood it, an invariant is a condition which holds both before and after an expression. They're, among other things, useful in proving that loop is correct, if I remember my Logic course correctly.

Is my description correct, or have I missed something? Have you ever used them in your program? And if so, how did they benefit?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_(computer_science)

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Yeah, I just read that actually. But it seems to me that invariants are only useful when you're trying to prove something. Is this correct (no pun intended)?

Comment: That's my understanding; when you're trying to reason about your program, to prove its correctness.

Comment: What is the difference with an assertion ?

Comment: @user9094:  An assertion is a declaration that something is true at a particular point in runtime, and is represented in the code.  An invariant is a statement (one hopes well-founded) that will always be true whenever it applies, and is not represented in the code itself.

Comment: Invariants are indeed useful for proving correctness, but they are not limited to that case. They are also useful for defensive-programming and during debugging. They don't just help prove your code is correct, they help reason about the code and find the location of the bugs close to the origins.

Comment: I am going to keep it short here and say that "Invariants are conditions that should be true for each instance(object) of a class whenever that object is visible to a client".

Comment: I've read *Coders at Work*, and can recall a lot of nonsense about "proofs". Programming is an empirical discipline, and invariants are only useful for empirical tests (i.e. unit tests) not for logical "proofs".

Answer (score 82):

In OOP, an invariant is a set of assertions that must always hold true during the life of an object for the program to be valid. It should hold true from the end of the constructor to the start of the destructor whenever the object is not currently executing a method that changes its state.

An example of invariant could be that exactly one of two member variables should be null. Or that if one has a given value, then the set of allowed values for the other is this or that...

I sometime use a member function of the object to check that the invariant holds. If this is not the case, an assert is raised. And the method is called at the start and exit of each method that changes the object (in C++, this is only one line...)

Comment: +1 for mentioning invariants need not be true in the middle of a executing method.

Comment: @Oddthinking Best to avoid that when possible though. It would be easy to enter an invarient-breaking state and forget to restore everything correctly before returning. Exceptions could also give you trouble.

Comment: @Alexander: For non-trivial invariants, it is almost impossible to avoid. If you need to update more than one variables in a method, as described in the answer, there is a point where only one has been updated and the invariant is false. There are enough constraints on writing good code without adding new ones.

Comment: @Oddthinking Yeah, it's often quite unavoidable. But for example, if there is a group of variables that logically belong together (e.g. an array, and the index of a "selected" item in the array), then it's probably worth extracting them to a type. From there, mutations of the array or the type can be expressed as a single assignment of a new instance of that type

Answer (score 54):

Well, the stuff I'm seeing in this thread is all great, but I have a definition of an 'invariant' that has been tremendously helpful for me at work.

> An invariant is any logical rule that must be obeyed throughout the execution of your program that can be communicated to a human, but not to your compiler.

This definition is helpful because it cleaves out conditions into two groups: those the compiler can be trusted with enforcing, and those that must be documented, discussed, commented, or otherwise communicated to contributors in order for them to interact with the codebase without introducing bugs.

Also, this definition is helpful because it allows you to use the generalization, "Invariants are bad".

As an example, the shifter in a manual transmission car is engineered to avoid an invariant.  If I wanted, I could build a transmission with one lever for each gear.  This lever could be forward ("engaged") or back ("disengaged").  In such a system, I have created an "invariant", which might be documented as such:

> "It is critical that the currently engaged gear be disengaged before a different gear is engaged.  To engage any two gears at the same time will cause mechanical stress that will tear the transmission apart.  Always disengage the currently engaged gear before engaging another."

And so, one might blame broken transmissions on sloppy driving.  Modern cars, however, use a single stick that pivots around among the gears.  It's designed in such a way that, on a modern stick-shift car, it is not possible to engage two gears at the same time.

In this way, we could say that the transmission has been engineered to 'remove the invariant', because it does not permit itself to be mechanically configured in a way that violates the logical rule.

Every invariant of this kind that you remove from your code is an improvement, because it lowers the cognitive load of working with it.

Comment: If an invariant is any logical rule that must be obeyed throughout the execution of your program, and your logical rule is that no two gears may be engaged at the same time, then is not the invariant that no two gears may be engaged at the same time? Without this invariant, your transmission could be in two gears at the same time, and thus tear itself apart. First, isn't a single stick shifter actually enforcing that invariant? Second, why would an invariant be intrinsically good or bad?

Comment: The comparison to car's gears is very clear to me. Thanks!

Comment: "An invariant is any logical rule that must be obeyed throughout the execution of your program that can be communicated to a human, but not to your compiler." - I quite like this, concise and easy to remember.

Comment: @DustinCleveland I think that in this example, the mechanisms behind the stick shift are the 'compiler' that 'enforces' the rules, whereas the driver that might otherwise cause an incident is one of the many clients that must consume and remember the information that's been "documented, discussed, commented, or otherwise communicated."

Comment: Brilliant explanation! I really understand now the reasoning on why having invariants in your code is bad practice.

Comment: This isn't the normal definition of invariant. And it also assumes that your language [makes it easy to express domain rules](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/11/wizards-and-warriors-part-five/)

Answer (score 5):

An invariant (in common sense) means some conditions that must be true at some point in time or even always while your program is executing. e.g. PreConditions and PostConditions can be used to assert some conditions that must be true when a function is called and when it returns. Object invariants can be used to assert that a object must have a valid state throughout the time it exists. This is the design by contract principle.
I have used invariants informally using checks in code. But more recently I am playing with the code [contracts library for .Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992) that directly supports invariants.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the following quote from Coders At Work...

> But once you know the invariant that it's maintaining, you can see,
>   ah, if we maintain that invariant then we'll get log lookup time.

...I guess "invariant" = "condition you want to maintain to ensure a desired effect".

It seems that invariant has two senses that differ in a subtle way:

1. Something that stays the same.
2. Something that you're trying to keep the same, in order to achieve goal X (such as a "log lookup time" above).

So 1 is like an assertion; 2 is like a tool for proving correctness, performance, or other properties - I think. See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_%28computer_science%29) for an example of 2 (proving the correctness of the solution to the MU puzzle).

Actually a 3rd sense of invariant is:

.3. What the program (or module or function) is supposed to do; in other words, its purpose.

From the same Coders At Work interview:

> But what makes big software manageable is having some global invariants or big-picture statements about what it's supposed to do and what things are supposed to be true.

Answer (score 4):

An invariant is like a rule or an assumption that can be used to dictate the logic of your program.

For example, suppose you have some software application that keeps track of user accounts. Suppose also that user can have multiple account, but for whatever reason you need to differentiate between a user's main account and "alias" accounts.

This could be a DB record or something else, but for now lets assume each user account is represented by a class object.

class userAccount
{
  private char * pUserName;
  private char * pParentAccountUserName;

...
}

An invariant might be the assumption that if pParentAccountUserName is NULL or empty then this object is the parent account. You can use this invariant to distinguish different types of account. There are probably better methods to distinguish different types of user accounts, so keep in mind this is just an example to show how an invariant might be used.

Comment: Invariants check the state of a program. They're not design decisions.

Comment: Invariants don't check anything. You can check the state of program to see if an invariant is TRUE or FALSE, but invariants themselves "do" nothing.

Comment: Typically, in C++ you would see some sort of class invariance such as member x must less than 25 and greater than 0. That is the invariant. Any checks against that invariant are assertions. In the example I have above, my invariant is if pParentAccountUserName is NULL or empty then it is a parent account. Invariants are designed decisions.

Comment: How do you check that if pParentAccountUserName is NULL or empty, this object is the parent account? Your statement only defines what a null/empty value is supposed to represent. The invariant is that the system conforms to that, i.e. that pParentAccountUserName can only be null or empty if it is a parent account. It's a subtle distinction.

Answer (score 2):

Coming from a physics background, in physics we have invariants, which are essentially quantities which do not vary throughout an entire computation/simulation. For instance, in physics, for a closed system total energy is conserved. Or again in physics, if two particle collide, the resulting fragments must contain exactly the energy they started with, and exactly the same momentum (a vector quantity). Usually there aren't enough invariants to totally specify the result. For instance in the 2particle collision, we have four invariants, three momentum components, and an energy component, but the system has six degrees of freedom (six numbers to describe its state). The invariants ought to be conserved to within rounding error, but their conservation does not prove the solution is correct.

So typically, these things are important as sanity checks, but by themselves they can't prove correctness.

Comment: -1 Invariants in physics are different. Calculating a solution is not the same as proving that an algorithm is correct. For the latter, invariants __can__ prove correctness.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the whole development process relies on invariants.

You write some code, that produces observable behaviour.

You then modify the code, with the goal that most of the observable behaviour remains invariant. When the invariant fails, you then `git diff` to figure out what change caused it to break.

Unit tests are used when the required invariant behaviours become too much to check in the development loop.

Learning to code is mostly about figuring out how to do this; i.e. decomposing the desired behaviour into a set of invariant behaviours which you are able to evolve into complex behaviours.

> A good example is the movement code for the game Celeste - 4k+ lines just to make it feel good.
>
> [source](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/mnqck2/comment/gtz8s20)

---

I've been talking about invariants between runs of the program. But when you hear someone say invariants they probably mean something that holds through out the lifetime of the program.

---

An **invariant** is something you can write a predicate for that returns `false` only when the program is incorrect.

---

An **invariant** is something you can write a hash function for such that the value of the hash only changes if the program is incorrect.